# Rudin’s PMA, Theorem 11.20

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence, measurable-functions

This is the definition which we need for the theorem: [(source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11MCl.png)

> **11.19 $\; \;$ Definition** $\; \;$Let $s$ be a real-valued function defined on $X$. If the range of $s$ is finite, we say that $s$ is a *simple function*.
>
> $\quad \quad$ Let $E \subset X$, and put
> $$
> K_{E}(x)= \begin{cases}1 & (x \in E), \\ 0 & (x \notin E).\end{cases}
> $$
>
> $K_{E}$ is called the *characteristic function* of $E$.
>
> $\quad \quad$ Suppose the range of $s$ consists of the distinct numbers $c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n}$. Let
> $$
> E_{i}=\left\{x \mid s(x)=c_{i}\right\} \quad(i=1, \ldots, n) .
> $$
> $\quad \quad$ Then
> $$
> s=\sum_{n=1}^{n} c_{l} K_{E_{1}},
> $$
>
> that is, every simple function is a finite linear combination of characteristic functions. It is clear that $s$ is measurable if and only if the sets $E_{1}, \ldots, E_{n}$ are measurable.
> $ \quad \quad$ It is of interest that every function can be approximated by simple functions:

Here is the theorem: [(source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuAHu.png)

> **11.20 $\; \;$ Theorem** $\; \;$ Let $f$ be a real function on $X$. There exists a sequence $\left\{s_{n}\right\}$ of simple functions such that $s_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for every $x \in X$. If $f$ is measurable, $\left\{s_{n}\right\}$ may be chosen to be a sequence of measurable functions. If $f \geq 0,\left\{s_{n}\right\}$ may be chosen to be a monotonically increasing sequence.
>
> $\quad$**Proof** $\; \;$ If $f \geq 0$, define
> $$
> E_{n i}=\left\{x \mid \frac{i-1}{2^{n}} \leq f(x)<\frac{i}{2^{n}}\right\}, \quad F_{n}=\{x \mid f(x) \geq n\}
> $$
> for $n=1,2,3, \ldots, i=1,2, \ldots, n 2^{n}$. Put
> $$
> s_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}} \frac{i-1}{2^{n}} K_{E_{n l}}+n K_{F_{n}} .
>  \quad \quad (50)$$
> In the general case, let $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$, and apply the preceding construction to $f^{+}$and to $f^{-}$.
>
> $\quad$ It may be noted that the sequence $\left\{s_{n}\right\}$ given by $(50)$ converges uniformly to $f$ if $f$ is bounded.

I couldn't understand that why does the sequence {$s_n$}, given by $(50)$ converge to $f$ .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How far is $s_n(x)$ from $f(x)$? The answer depends rather little on the value $f(x)$.

Comment: Fix a point $x$. Think about whether or not $s_n(x)$ is eventually equal to $f(x)$. If you break down what the $K$-series really means, it follows quickly.

Comment: @FShrike could you answer explicitly?

Comment: I do not have the time right now. I promise you that the only way to understand it, really, is to understand exactly what $s_n(x)$ means. Try *bounding* $|s_n(x)-f(x)|$, holding $x$ fixed

Comment: @FShrike  I don't understand what is $K_{E_{n_1}}$ equal of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n(x)=f(x)$:**

Suppose $f$ is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$-valued.

Let $x \in X$. Since $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, there is a positive integer $M$ so that $0 \leq f(x) <M$. This means we will have
\begin{aligned}s_{M}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{M 2^{M}} \frac{i-1}{2^{M}} K_{E_{M i}}(x)+M K_{F_{M}}(x)&=\sum_{i=1}^{M 2^{M}} \frac{i-1}{2^{M}} K_{E_{M i}}(x)+M \cdot0\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{M 2^{M}} \frac{i-1}{2^{M}} K_{E_{M i}}(x).
\end{aligned}
Now we may repeat the proceeding corresponding argument for uniform convergence in the case that $f$ is bounded to similarly conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |s_n(x)-f(x)|=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=0$.

---

**$f$ bounded $\implies$ $s_n \to f$ uniformly:**

Suppose $f$ is bounded. This means there is a positive integer $M$ so that $0 \leq f(x) <M$ (assuming $f$ nonnegative to spare some headache).

Notice we have
\begin{aligned}s_{M}=\sum_{i=1}^{M 2^{M}} \frac{i-1}{2^{M}} K_{E_{M i}}+M K_{F_{M}}=\sum_{i=1}^{M 2^{M}} \frac{i-1}{2^{M}} K_{E_{M i}}+M \cdot0=\sum_{i=1}^{M 2^{M}} \frac{i-1}{2^{M}} K_{E_{M i}}.
\end{aligned}
So if $n \geq M$ and $x \in X$, then we have
\begin{aligned}|s_{n}(x)-f(x)|&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}} \frac{i-1}{2^{n}} K_{E_{n i}}(x)-f(x)\right|
\\&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}} \frac{i-1}{2^{n}} K_{E_{n i}}(x)-\sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}}f(x)K_{E_{n i}}(x)\right|
\\&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}} \left(\frac{i-1}{2^{n}}-f(x)\right) K_{E_{n i}}(x)\right|
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n2^{n}}\left( f(x) -\frac{i-1}{2^{n}}\right)K_{E_{n i}}(x) \quad \quad \left(f(x) -\frac{i-1}{n} < 0 \implies  K_{E_{n i}}(x)=0 \right)
\\&< \sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}} \frac{1}{2^n}K_{E_{n i}}(x)
\\&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}} K_{E_{n i}}(x)
\\&=\frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{aligned}

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given.

By the Archimedean Principle, there is a positive integer $L$ so that $L\varepsilon>1$. Consider $N=\max\{M,L\}$. So if $n \geq N$, then we have
$$\sup_{x \in X} \left|s_n(x)-f(x) \right|< \varepsilon.$$

Comment: @M A Pelto I couldn't the second equality. ( When you remove the absolute value sign)

Comment: Write $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n 2^{n}}f(x)K_{E_{n i}}(x)$. Since $0 \leq f(x)K_{E_{n i}}(x)<\frac{i}{2^n}K_{E_{n i}}(x) $, it follows that $0 \leq \left( f(x) -\frac{i-1}{2^n}\right) K_{E_{n i}}(x) <\left(\frac{i}{2^n}-\frac{i-1}{2^n}\right)K_{E_{n i}}(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}K_{E_{n i}}(x)$.
Note: it is important to keep in mind that $\frac{i-1}{2^n} \leq f(x) <\frac{i}{2^n}$ on $E_{n i}$.

Comment: @M A Pelto I meant above this man. above the sign "<"

Comment: What is the absolute value of something that is greater than or equal to zero???

Comment: Thank you man. God bless you

Comment: @M A Pelto  In what did you use this $\quad \quad \quad \left(f(x) -\frac{i-1}{n} < 0 \implies  K_{E_{n i}}=0 \right)$ ?

Comment: Sorry if unclear, it is supposed to read $K_{E_{ni}}(x)=0$ or, in other words, $x \notin E_{ni}$. I just added this to clarify the fact that we drop the absolute value by noticing that for each term of the series, the first factor is either nonnegative or else the second factor is zero. :D

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f : X \to [0, \infty]$ is measurable. Realize that for $x \in X$, $$s_n(x) = \min(\lfloor\frac{f(x)}{2^{-n}}\rfloor 2^{-n}, n).$$
In words, if $f(x) \leq n$, we let $s_n(x)$ be the largest multiple of $2^{-n}$ that is $\leq f(x)$, and if $f(x) \geq n$, we let $s_n(x) = n$. Now it is clear that for $x \in X$, if $f(x) < \infty$, then for $n \geq f(x)$ we have $s_n(x) \leq f(x) < s_n(x) + 2^{-n}$. So for $n \geq f(x)$, $|s_n(x) - f(x)| \leq 2^{-n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. This proves that $s_n \to f$ pointwise.

Now suppose $f$ is bounded. Then there is $M > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in X$. So for $n \geq M$, for all $x \in X$, $|s_n(x) - f(x)| \leq 2^{-n}$. So for $n \geq M$, $\sup_{x \in X}|s_n(x) - f(x)| \leq 2^{-n} \to 0$. This shows that $s_n \to f$ uniformly.